# how to exclude particular class from keep class tag proguard

Tags: proguard, android-proguard

I have multiple classes in one package. I am keeping all these classes with a single rule

> -keep class com.something.folder.** { *; }.

How can I obfuscate one particular class from that package?

Answer (score 3):

You can use an exclusion pattern like this:

```
-keep class !com.example.A,com.example.** { *; }
```

This will keep all classes in the package `com.example` and sub-packages, except for class `com.example.A`.

ProGuard will analyze the provided patterns in sequential order, and stop if it encounters a matching one. Thus you need to make sure that the exclusion pattern comes first.